# Table with multiple lookups

Tags: sql-server, relational-theory

I bet this may be a duplicate and I'm not forming the question correctly, so feel free to point me in the right direction.

### Background

We have a SQL Server with some legacy data. They're all addresses, but stored in separate tables (I know, ugh.) so, we have a `tblDefenseCounsel`, `tblPlaintiffCounsel`, `tblVendor`, `tblInsurer`, etc., all with addresses. I don't have the ability to change that currently unfortunately.

We are creating a new table for a feature that has to store a contact -- except the contact can be from any of those locations.

### Goal

Organize this generic contact table in a way that will cause us the least amount of agony.

### Choices

As I see it, we have the following choices:

- Create a Table such as `| TableReferenceID | ContactID |` with a lookup table that stores the database tables its from
- Create a table such as `| TableName | ContactID |`, which stores the table name in text
- Some third option?

### Question

What is the proper way to store data of this nature, or what are the valid options? Are there additional options besides those I've listed?

Comment: What is a "contact" in this context? Just a name and phone number?

Comment: @MarkWilkinson in this case it's a name, address, and phone number, and all generally for businesses.

Comment: In that case, similar to what Matt says, I would think you would need to create a table to store the contact info, and then a relationship table for each table that could have a contact. For example, `tblDefenseCounsel` would have a corresponding relationship table called  `tblDefenseCounselContact`. That table would have 2 columns: `tblDefenseCounselID` and `ContactID`. This is all assuming you can't touch the existing schema.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered modeling where contact info exists independent of type. Could a contact be used for defense counsel and latter for vendor?

Assuming you are trying to fix the data and hide it from the program might i suggest the following:

1. Create a generic contact table and import all contacts here
2. Create bridge tables like `tblDefenseCounselContacts` with (oldID,ContactID)
3. View to replace `tblDefenseCounsel` and triggers as needed.
4. repeat for other tables.